# Can't find why inodes running out

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, inode

I have a Xen VPS with Debian Linux installed with ext4 filesystem. Once I found that all inodes are used. I checked this:

```
~# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs         3932160 3932160     0  100% /
udev             59227     262 58965    1% /dev
tmpfs            63251     215 63036    1% /run
/dev/xvda      3932160 3932160     0  100% /
tmpfs            63251       2 63249    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            63251       2 63249    1% /run/shm
```

Then I tryed to find where all inodes were used. Usually them were used by PHP session files (bacause of cron task or PHP internal cleaner were broken). But I can't find what directory contains very large amount of files. I tryed many methods, there is one:

```
/# for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
/aquota.group
1
/aquota.user
1
/bin
124
/boot
9
/dev
264
/etc
1746
/home
1
/initrd.img
1
/lib
4002
/lib64
2
/lost+found
1
/media
1
/mnt
1
/opt
1
/proc
26590
/root
17
/run
214
/sbin
127
/selinux
1
/srv
3
/sys
3609
/tmp
1
/usr
37020
/var
8636
/vmlinuz
1

/# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=59227,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=50604k,mode=755)
/dev/xvda on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered,usrquota,grpquota)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=101200k)

Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs         rootfs    61927420 37390672  21391020  64% /
udev           devtmpfs     10240        0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs        50604      120     50484   1% /run
/dev/xvda      ext4      61927420 37390672  21391020  64% /
tmpfs          tmpfs         5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs       101200        0    101200   0% /run/shm

/# find . | wc -l
78898
```

What can I do next?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your find command to exclude inodes belonging to other mount points, include -xdev on the find command line. The 78898 at the end of your output is probably more than the total number of files visible to find in the rootfs partition, because it includes files underneath other mount points. This much does not explain the discrepancy you asked about; it just means the actual discrepancy is probably somewhat larger.

The first thing to check is whether you have unlinked open files. The output of the following command, run as root, should show you those:

```
lsof +L1
```

One example of why you might have open unlinked files is processes which began before package upgrades which replaced them with newer files (a couple of sshd processes on one of my systems have open unlinked files). Another possibility is processes which deliberately unlink open files to conceal their contents from other processes.

If that doesn't fully account for the discrepancy, another possibility is that files which have not been deleted are still invisible to the find command because they are hidden underneath other mount points. There are various ways to investigate that possibility, but it probably makes sense to count open deleted files first.